# Meaning of "strike dread"

Tags: meaning, phrases

What is the meaning of the phrase *strike dread*? I've encountered it many times.

Comment: I would suggest you to make a good use of your dictionary when you encounter an unfamiliar phrase.

Comment: Also *strike fear, strike terror, strike awe*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is nothing mystical about *strike dread*:

- Strike: to hit with sudden force
- Dread: a terror or great fear

To *strike dread into someone's heart* is to inspire a sudden fear.